# What type of HTML table is this and what type of webscraping techniques can you use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to extract data within in this link, http://www.rchsd.org/doctors/index.htm?strt=0&ln=&fn=&sp=&grp=&loc=&lng=&gen=, with `R` but it is rather difficult.

I notice that the url link does not change whenever I click on a page number. Is this table created with JavaScript? Is the table created by some external source and how can I get access to it? Also, is there a technical name for this type of table?

Also, for anyone who knows *web scraping* with `R` or any other program, how would you extract all the data from this table? I tried using the following code in `R` to extract the data, but I get `NULL`. How would you address this issue?

```
mps <- paste("http://www.va.gov/providerinfo/SANDIEGO/index.asp?servicesearch=&specialtysearch=&gendersearch=&sort=&currentPage=1") 
mps.doc <- htmlParse(mps)
mps.tabs <- readHTMLTable(mps.doc)
```

Also, if you can not anwer the second half of my question, that is okay. I mainly want to know the answer of the first half of my question.

Comment: Well I see the page url change to, for example, `&currentPage=2`. Also when I click a letter

Comment: I observe the form data being sent with `POST` and the response being an ordinary static table filled with data.

Comment: I observe the URL does change when clicking a page number. The url is - again - just a static page.

Comment: There's lots of jQuery and jQuery-UI being loaded in the page header, but it doesn't look like any of it is being used!

Comment: I accidentally put the wrong link. But, I changed it now. How exactly can you web-scrape with Jquery? What functions would you use?

Comment: @John Wu, look at my previous comment which will teach you how via `jQuery` and simple `.ajax()` method. Examples: your original link produces these [**original link results - use Tree View**](http://y.ahoo.it/tmXT3), while your updated link produces these [**updated link results - use Tee View**](http://y.ahoo.it/tRxfl)

Comment: I love the comment in the source of that page `//This is ugly - I apologize to whoever is reading this. I swear I'm going to turn this into a plugin soon.`

Comment: @arttronics How exactly did you find this link, http://www.rchsd.org/api/physdir/? Also, I would like to see a link similar to the one that you found except for this website http://doctors.ucsd.edu/?index=1 How can I find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Answer Revised with 3 different techniques, all .ajax() and YQL based.***

## Technique 1

**Reference HTML:** http://doctors.ucsd.edu/?index=1

For the first part of your question, the type of table in the URL you provided is a standard [**HTML Table Model**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html) variety. In creating that `table`, the website uses a **XML File** to populate it's `rows` and `columns` with data, including the photo of the doctor.

To keep the servers happy, not all of the data from the **XML File** is loaded into the browser, only *limited results* are shown with the option to proceed to the next page.

This is also true for the URL link in the comments section you wrote about (i.e. http://doctors.ucsd.edu/?index=1) where the visitor can select 10, 25 or 50 results from the webpages ***Results Per Page*** dropdown menu. The web's address bar will show that number ***requested*** via **`&setsize=25`** for example.

Although you may want to [**data scrape that reference URL**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdoctors.ucsd.edu%2F%3Fsetsize%3D5%22), it's best not to since ***you already have*** the **XML file** with all the data you need. ***It's less work to access it directly!***

**Reference XML:** http://www.rchsd.org/api/physdir/

The second part of your question is easy enough since the **XML File** is readily available. This time around, when you [**data scrape that reference XML File**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20phys%20FROM%20xml%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rchsd.org%2Fapi%2Fphysdir%2F%22%20LIMIT%205), it will show the information your looking for quickly and with very much readability too.

I've limited the request to 5 results for testing purposes in ***both data scraping queries above***, but you can increase that to a *larger sampling value*. The amount of extra webpage data in the 1st example would require the use of `XPATH` to map out nodes and require extra processing to use that data.

I've prepared a detailed jsFiddle which should explain a lot of your questions about this process. In it, I explain how to use YQL, `.ajax()`, and the link for the **XML File**.

**Reference Example:**

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20phys%20FROM%20xml%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rchsd.org%2Fapi%2Fphysdir%2F%22%20LIMIT%205',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        var dataResults = $(data).find('results');
        console.log(dataResults);
    }
});
```

**Reference Tutorial:**
[**jsFiddle Data Scraping XML Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Ck6h/1/) (*See below for jsFiddle HTML Demo*)

---

## Technique 2

**EDIT:** Returning to ***original*** reference HTML: http://doctors.ucsd.edu/?index=1

The *last thing* I wrote in the first section is ***actually not true***, as you don't *necessarily* have all the data you need. While you can create your own *Google Map Location Data* from the physical doctors address in the **XML File**, that information is already available to use.

It's then also discovered that this URL also contains a unique formatted ***Thumbnail Image*** and includes ***Doctors Information*** section when available.

So then, what follows is a re-written jsFiddle that shows how to data scrape that HTML webpage. You'll note in this new jsFiddle that the *YQL Statement* is no longer `ACCESS phys FROM xml` since we are now dealing with a HTML document. Also, we are going to use wild card `*` and not tagname `phys` in that *YQL Statement*. It will then be `ACCESS * FROM html`

As you remember from above *data scraping 1st method*, too much data was returned from that request. I'll explain how to add an [**`XPATH`**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-select-xpath.html) to that *YQL Statement* so you only get the desired data back.

Where to start you ask? At that website in your browser! I'll use Firefox to continue.

First, let's force 5 results to be returned in our tests. To do this, change **Results Per Page** to 25, then at the browser bar change the 25 to 5 for `&setsize=` query. Hit enter on your keyboard to apply changes.

Using the webpages **Additional Search Criteria**, **Show More Specialties**, **Location**, and **Sort results by:** will also modify the browsers bar and further create a customize URL to use.

For our Demo, we need just 1 additional customization of **Sort results by: Last Name A-Z**. Reload the webpage if need be, and to be sure... our customized URL should look like:

http://doctors.ucsd.edu/?sortby=familyName&sortDirection=asc&setsize=5

Now that the webpage is populated with our requested 5 results, we need to see how the layout is supporting those items.

Use Firefox **Inspect Element** tool via right-click on your mouse to view and learn the *table layout structure*. Soon, you will see that all the results returned are enclosed in a ***unique class name***.

Here is a screenshot of using Firefox to illustrate:

[image]

When *popping up* the *HTML Panel* via the icon at bottom of **Inspect Element** tools (*to the right side of Inspect Element Icon*), you can see how the `layout` is for that single Doctors box:

[image]

In the photo above, you can **visually** *traverse up the DOM* to see the main *classname* `resultsList` is the `div` holding the requested 5 results. That actual classname is *can be used*, but a more ***refined classname*** to use is the **`resultsListProvider`** that each returned item carries.

You now have the required information to construct a YQL Statement to use. First, here's the minimum we will use to get started:

```html
ACCESS * FROM html WHERE url="http://doctors.ucsd.edu/?sortby=familyName&sortDirection=asc&setsize=5"
```

The above really will not do since it returns too much non essential webpage data, that's why we used **Inspect Element** to discover what's really important. That being said, we will use [**`XPATH`**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-select-xpath.html) to access the part of the webpage we need via *classname* **`resultsListProvider`**.

```html
xpath="//div[@class='resultsListProvider']"
```

Now we can combine *both parts* using `AND` to create the [**Final YQL Statement**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdoctors.ucsd.edu%2F%3Fsortby%3DfamilyName%26sortDirection%3Dasc%26setsize%3D5%22%20AND%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D'resultsListProvider'%5D%22) that we can data scrape:

```html
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://doctors.ucsd.edu/?sortby=familyName&sortDirection=asc&setsize=5" AND xpath="//div[@class='resultsListProvider']"
```

The **Final YQL Statement** above will now provide usable results to work with in a new jsFiddle I've created, which has updated comments to reflect these changes. If you need to, you can combine both **XML File** and **HTML URL** methods to satisfy your data scraping requirements, as each method provides content that other method may lack.

Reminder: Some data might be directly rendered when the webpage loads or when using **YQL Rest State** query. That means ***your dynamic data*** might be based on ***their dynamic data***. *Oh my!*

**Reference Tutorial:**

[**jsFiddle Data Scraping HTML Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2EYKd/1/) (*See above for jsFiddle XML Demo*)

---

## Technique 3

**EDIT 2: Using HTML Directly**

[**jsFiddle Data Scraping HTML Demo: Clone That Webpage**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xvFbJ/)

The latest edit shows how to use the original webpage's style sheets (*which is optional, you can create your own*), but requests the Ajax data differently using `dataType` attribute. Using this approach places the the exact markup on the local webpage, including any `classnames` or `id's` with it.

jsFiddle Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Alternate non-tutorial [**jsFiddle Data Scraping HTML Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2EYKd/1/) version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input arttronics :)

Comment: Okay so here is the website that I would like to web-scrape. http://goo.gl/tzhaN      I would like to know how to find the xml version of all the doctor's data. This is unique as the url does not change as you browse down to look for more doctors. Also, the data expands, as you click on a button.

Comment: I visited the long-link, except I receive an error stating the site has technical difficulties, and yet I can start a new search. I also analyzed a separate search from scratch and did not see any XML files accessed, only the form inputs appear to narrow the search criteria. Since data scraping only works with either an opened-ended API or direct access to a webpage that already has the results (i.e., form not required), I dont see much luck in scraping that website. Using [YQL](http://y.ahoo.it/FU7rm) shows the long-link uses the encryption in the Address Bar to access the data you require.

Answer (score 2):

The table is formed using this [XML](http://www.rchsd.org/api/physdir/)

Comment: Turns out that you don't even need to scrape =). It's your lucky day I guess

Comment: +1, I think negating for simple answers that are not blindingly obvious is a bit harsh. It shouldn't always need that there be paragraphs to get an upvote.